# Is regularization only for regression?

Tags: classification, regularization

I am making a classification model. I understand that the regularization minimizes loss functions. Can i use regularization techniques to minimize loss function in classification if doing so is possible. Please help me with some suggestions or useful links.

Comment: Yes, you can use regularization for classification. Check Deep Learning with Python Book.

Comment: Yes, the same types of regularization that are used for regression can also be used for classification. You can check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365778/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-generalize-well/365806#365806) which describes some regularization techniques.

Comment: Regularization does NOT minimize loss functions. Regularization usually increases loss function, but often offers better generalization.